# Hide a class of elements when any img clicked

Tags: javascript, web, jsfiddle, dom-manipulation

I am trying to write a javascript for hidding all elements of the class "prewrap", when any image on 
the webpage is clicked.

Code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hidepre() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("prewrap");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].style.visibility === "hidden") {
            elems[i].style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            elems[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].onclick = "hidepre()";
}
</script>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aX5kQ/

But this is not working at all, any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Check this [update](http://jsfiddle.net/aX5kQ/4/). Is this what you want? (I just removed the `<script>` tag from the JS section.

Comment: Almost, can I make the prewrap disappear all together, without even whitespace?

Comment: For that, you need to set the `display` property to `none`, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/aX5kQ/6/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, check this fiddle <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aX5kQ/5/)**</kbd>

**EDIT**

Remove the `script` tag from your `jsfiddle` leave only the code.

```
   function hidepre() { 
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("prewrap");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].style.display === "none") {
            elems[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            elems[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].onclick = hidepre;
}
```

Also in your post this line should be corrected ->

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].onclick = hidepre; //this line - here should only be the name of the function without quotes and parentheses 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine if you remove the `script` tag from the JS area of jsfiddle (*you put raw javascript in there.. no tags*)

edited demo at http://jsfiddle.net/aX5kQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hi this code is executed immediately before the image is loaded and so no img is found.

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].onclick = "hidepre()";
}
```

Execute this when the DOM is finished loading with `window.onload = ...`